# ProgressDialog won't dismiss in Thread

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-progressbar

I am new to Android dev, and am trying to solve this problem that has been giving me some frustration. I am trying to close this progressDialog. When I run the app, it displays, the information is fetched, and the UI is updated. However, the dialog is never dismissed.

```
progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeActivity.this, "", "Fetching info...", true, false); 
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        fetchInfomation(userID); //fetches information - Works
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { 
                setLayoutList(); //updates UI - Works
                progDialog.dismiss(); //doesn't seem to close progress dialog
                firstView(); //displays prompt - Works 
            }
        });   
        progDialog.dismiss(); //doesn't close dialog either
    }
}).start();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/891451/696723. you'll get some ideas from it

Answer (score 0):

You can't interact with UI inside an external thread. There is some techniques to do that but it's not necessary.

You can use [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

For example:

```
...
private Handler mHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case 0: ...
                case 1: ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
....
new Thread() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
            ... // do your background jobs here
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(...); // interact with UI
        });   
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be good practice if you do any GUI updates on UI thread. Inside any thread you can run your UI thread where you can do the UI stuffs or else you can go for message handler also which will do the same for you.

```
Runnable run_in_ui = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do your UI stuffs here
    }
};
runOnUiThread(run_in_ui);
```