# Android DialogButton not dismissing

Tags: android

My `DialogButton` is not dismissing even though I have `.dismiss()` in it. My code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.iabout);
    // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.iabout);


    dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btAboutOK);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }); 
}
```

appreciate any help.

Comment: Where do you call the dialog.show() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please dont use dialog's, please use [DialogFragments](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html). The are much easier to maintain.
*(For pre honeycomb add the support library to your project)*

Then in your `DialogFragment` class use the `AlertDialog.Builder` in the `onCreateDialog(Bdl bundle)` like so:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
            .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_custom_title)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        ((MyActivity)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                    }
                }
            )
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        ((MyActivity)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                    }
                }
            )
            .create();
}

}
```

These examples can be found [here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#BasicDialog)

At the very lease if you are going to use the old way of using dialogs please at least use the [dialog builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html).

Then as per the example above you can set the callback methods.

If you you want to do custom dialogs with custom layouts, the use `DialogFragment`s, then you can control the dialogs lifecycle correctly and then your custom button can just call `dismiss()` in the `DialogFragment`.

Read the examples as mentioned [here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#BasicDialog)

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3378859/975959, the issue could be because you placed your dialog within the `onCreate()` method.

Though this answer is regarding issues with orientation changes, but it might be goot to consider their answer:
moving the dialog implementation to the

```
@Override
onPostCreate()
```

method.
Hope this helps.

Also you could add `setCancelable(true)` allowing your dialog to be dismissed using the back button